# Xcode unexpectedly quits after archieve

Tags: mac, ios-appstore, xcode

I am using flutter and I am not very good at Xcode. I upload to the app store my project. When I try update the application I got this problem. Xcode unexpectedly quits and open another window that showing lots of description as follows:

[image]

Following is the description text:

```
Process:               Xcode [62297]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               12.5 (18205)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-18205000000000000~3 (12E262)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       841326589
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [62297]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2021-10-07 10:24:11.319 +0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F3F89A00-9F08-437B-4FFA-CD19864AC0FF

Sleep/Wake UUID:       8AD975D5-E424-4070-9BAD-B4BE60D96FCF

Time Awake Since Boot: 55000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: -[DVTSourceControlWorkspace init] (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 12E262
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
UserInfo: (null)
Open FDs: 41/7168
Hints: 
 
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:] (in Foundation)
  4   -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] (in DVTSourceControl)
  5   __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
  6   __107-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:includingManagedWorkingCopies:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTSourceControl)
  7   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
  8   -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
  9   __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ (in Foundation)
 10   -[NSOperation start] (in Foundation)
 11   __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ (in Foundation)
 12   __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 13   _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 20   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2054487b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010338ba4f DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 424
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff2027cd92 objc_exception_throw + 48
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff2122a899 -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:] + 0
4   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010847146a -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] + 118
5   IDEFoundation                       0x000000010419e092 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 112
6   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010845ebe3 __107-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:includingManagedWorkingCopies:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 5069
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff212384cf __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff212383c7 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff2123835a __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff2123760e -[NSOperation start] + 785
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff212372df __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
12  Foundation                          0x00007fff212371b2 __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2023419e _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20227806 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2022a1b0 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 423
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20229887 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 708
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20236818 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20236f70 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff203ce417 _pthread_wqthread + 244
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff203cd42f start_wqthread + 15

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff28706ab3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff28706815 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 587
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff287065b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22cc96f2 _DPSNextEvent + 864
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22cc7ec5 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1364
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000103a71781 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 421
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22cba239 -[NSApplication run] + 586
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c8e47c NSApplicationMain + 816
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff203ecf5d start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21256647 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001189be93f +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 188
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2124f477 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21256647 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001189cc6e3 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 242
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2124f477 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203a4656 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f10d3 __CFSocketManager + 630
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 4:: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039ecde __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d1e49 _pthread_cond_wait + 1298
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff2033ad72 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff37464e44 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 84
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff3746991b bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 251
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff374694f9 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff3746aba7 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 39
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e4f68a _NSEventThread + 124
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21256647 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff212e4511 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000012cdc8b5d -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 126
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2124f477 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2039c62c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204cab5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c923f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204c864c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2054ef52 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x0000000136447afe closure #1 in FSEventStream.start() + 254
7   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x00000001364180da closure #1 in Thread.init(task:) + 106
8   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x00000001364181fe thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
9   libSwiftPM.dylib                0x00000001364181d6 @objc ThreadImpl.main() + 38
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2124f477 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203d18fc _pthread_start + 224
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203cd443 thread_start + 15

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.5G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.5G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.2G(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               896K        7 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 2880K        6 
CG image                          1096K       92 
CG raster data                      36K        4 
CoreAnimation                     20.9M      242 
CoreData                            12K        1 
CoreGraphics                        12K        2 
CoreImage                            8K        2 
CoreUI image data                 1864K       15 
Dispatch continuations            32.0M        1 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Image IO                            56K        8 
JS JIT generated code              1.0G        3 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           159.9M      153 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       12 
Performance tool data                4K        1         not counted in TOTAL below
SQLite page cache                  192K        3 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       16 
Stack                             15.6M       16 
VM_ALLOCATE                        280K       18 
WebKit Malloc                     1128K        2 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            63.2M      897 
__DATA_CONST                      44.7M      657 
__DATA_DIRTY                      2458K      273 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       672.7M      426 
__OBJC_RO                         70.2M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2480K        2 
__TEXT                           838.3M      855 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
libnetwork                        1152K       16 
mapped file                      301.6M       72 
shared memory                      760K       16 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              3.2G     3824 

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM 427.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 2,7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: kHW_IntelIris6100Item, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54424C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54424C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1680.8)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.5d7, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121,33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Redmi Note 8
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

If I open another project on Xcode there is no problem. Could you help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly consider sharing further details about the issue you are facing to help with an answer that can address your concern. In this case, share either a screenshot of the other window (which contains crash log) or share the text displayed by the crash log.

Comment: I shared screenshot of the window and crash logs. Could you take a look for this please.

Comment: This may be the perfect question on how to get started in macOS development.. I concur on the Welcome to Ask Different feeling.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to the practice of being a developer and the time honored practice of asking for volunteer help to learn the craft.

You can do two things here:

1. Act as a customer and get support from Apple Developer team to update and resolve the Xcode crash (run updates, open a ticket, restart and try making a more simple document in the app that crashes hoping to discover and isolate the [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) to cause Xcode to crash).
2. Act as a developer and dig in to analyze exactly what happened and grow your skill at reading crash and system logs on macOS.

If you choose 2 here is the best place to start down that learning path:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-using-crash-reports-and-device-logs

You have all the tools to start inspecting and debugging this save the source code for Xcode itself but you can decompile that if needed, it just takes time and experience.

Comment: I skipped the obvious choice 3 - hire someone to handle this for you (they will do either step 1 or step 2 for you and report back and take your money in exchange)